# how to install mathlib in my lake4 toolchain?

Tags: lean

I know this is a basic question but I've been struggling to figure this out for the past day and I'm not making progress. I can download and build the source files for mathlib4, and if I just add my own .lean file in that directory then I can `import Mathlib` without issue, but I can't figure out how to import it from anywhere else. Ideally I would like to add mathlib to the libraries in my toolchain, but I can't find any information on how to do that either. Am I just missing something about how this system is supposed to work?

Comment: I presume you tried this: https://leanprover-community.github.io/get_started.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ecosystem of lean4 has gone through some changes since lean3, where this was often done via [leanproject](https://leanprover-community.github.io/leanproject.html), so the question isn't necessarily basic. There are multiple ways of doing this (e.g. cloning the whole mathlib4 repo), but the most flexible way is using the **new** package manager for lean named [lake](https://github.com/leanprover/lake). If you have installed your lean toolchain via [elan](https://github.com/leanprover/elan), you should have a working lake version already. You can then run

```
lake new <package-name> math
```

to create a lake package that has mathlib4 as a dependency, check the `lakefile.lean` in your project, if you want to know more.
Next run

```
lake build
```

and you should be good to go!

Comment: so there's no way to import Mathlib from a standalone file that isn't part of a project?

Comment: this option was available in [lean3](https://leanprover-community.github.io/leanproject.html#global-mathlib-install), in theory it should be possible with lean4 by fiddling with the way where lean looks for imports (e.g. `lean --root=dirofmathlib`, but I haven't tried that